# Double Quotes in batch string redux

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping

I'm trying to understand how the ^ Caret escape works in a Batch CMD. Lets say I type this line in a CMD Window, I would expect it to send the DIR listing to "c:\my text.txt"

```
CMD.EXE "/C > ^"c:\my text.txt^" DIR C:\*.*"
```

Instead I get the error:

```
'txt.txt" DIR *.*"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

If I do something as simple as this:

```
ECHO "^"^""

Expected: """"
Actual  : "^"""
```

Even if I try double quoting like this:

```
ECHO " "" "" "

Expected: " " " "
Actual  : " "" "" "
```

Can someone 'splain how this works and what is a reliable way is to escape double quotes in a command line?

Thanks.

**Additional Example:**

Why does this work:

```
cmd.exe "/C sqlcmd.exe -S.\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q"select suser_name()" > "c:\temp\test 1.txt""
```

but this gives error "The system cannot find the path specified." and does not create the txt file.

```
cmd.exe "/C "sqlcmd.exe" -S.\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q"select suser_name()" > "c:\temp\test 1.txt""
```

I know it is not needed in this case, but how would I enclose the command sqlcmd.exe in quotes?

I also tried removing the quotes from the whole line with the same results, i.e.,

```
cmd.exe /C "sqlcmd.exe" -S.\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q"select suser_name()" > "c:\temp\test 1.txt"
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are a state machine within cmd.exe. The first quote turns quoting semantics on, the next quote turns it off, the next back on, etc.

It is possible to escape a quote such that it does not turn quote semantics on.

For example, the following will send a quote character to test.txt

```
echo ^" >test.txt
```

Without the escape, the string `" >test.txt` is simply printed to the screen.

Unfortunately, it is ***not possible*** to escape a quote that turns off quote semantics.

For example, suppose you want to print the string `"hello world" >"test.txt"` to the screen. None of the techniques you tried will work because an internal quote cannot be escaped. The `^"` form treats the `^` as a literal, and the output will still be redirected to a file. The `""` for properly quotes the `>`, so there is no redirection, but now you have two quotes instead of one.

You have two options.

**1) escape all "poison" characters that are not quoted**

```
echo "hello world" ^>"test.txt"
```

**2) hide the quote literal within a delayed expansion variable**

I'm assuming this code is in a batch script.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "quote=""
echo "hello world!quote! >!quote!test.txt"
```

Note that using this technique can become tricky if dealing with `FOR /F ... IN('command')` or `CMD /C` because delayed expansion will probably be off within the new CMD.EXE context.

---

Here is a way to do your original command

```
cmd /c dir c:\*.* ^>"c:\my text.txt"
```

Note that the entire command string after `/c` does not have to be enclosed within quotes. In this case, it is easier if it is not.

---

I believe your new command at the end can be written as follows:

```
cmd.exe /C ""sqlcmd.exe" -S.\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q"select suser_name()" > "c:\temp\test 1.txt""
```

If used within a parenthesized block, then the right paren will need to be escaped.

```
(
  cmd.exe /C ""sqlcmd.exe" -S.\SQLEXPRESS -E -Q"select suser_name(^)" > "c:\temp\test 1.txt""
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added an Additional Example above as the comments allow limited formatting. I tried using your suggestions but still no luck.

Comment: @Neilw - I tested the code in my answer, and they all work (I had forgotten to include the `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` - edit has been made). I haven't had a chance to work on the more complicated command in your edited answer.

Comment: @Neilw - OK, I think I have a solution for your updated question.